# grails plugin not listed in netbeans

Tags: grails

recently I right click on my grails project in netbeans and select plugins. Only 2 plugins are listed available for install. Why is thia so? Is there a bug in netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

It seems Grails had some issues with loading the plugins for a bit. The problem was addressed [here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Apologies-for-the-recent-disruption-td4629743.html), and it should be fixed.